# TFS Source Control allowed us to check-in a file that wasn't the latest version

Tags: tfs, version-control, tfvc

We are using Team Foundation Source Control and one of our users didn't do a "Get Latest Version" on a project we were working on. After the user made changes (to an outdated version), they were able to check-in their changes without any issue.

This meant that any previous change that they didn't have in their workspace before making changes were completely overwritten.

We did a test on a separate project whereby I made a change, then another user made a change to the same file (but didn't do a get latest version so they didn't have the most recent version from source control). They were able to successfully check-in.

How could this happen? I've used GIT before and this is not possible as it should raise a conflict that needs to be resolved.

Comment: My guess would be that you, or they, or whoever, is working `disconnected` from TFS at the time. That or you should ensure that the clients are set to prompt to get latest version on check out.

Comment: I know of a few cases that can cause this to happen, but you either need to try to check in previously (automatically resolving the conflict), or force the checkin. it would be helpful if you could supply the exact steps with screenshots or commandline commands.

Comment: What version of TFS are you using? What version of Visual Studio are you using (in both cases)? For each system, are you using either Local or Server workspaces?

Comment: We are using 2012 for both. Ill provide some screenshots.

Comment: We are using 2012 for both. Ill provide some screenshots. Our clients aren't working disconnected, we are using local workspaces and we actually have option to get latest version on checkout ticked. I'm going to do some screenshots to try and replicate.

Comment: We are actually using server workspaces. Not sure if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have the "Attempt to Automatically resolve conflicts when they are generated" turned on, which will attempt to resolve the conflicts automatically if it can:

[image]

But even if this case, even though conflicts are recolved automatically, the checkin is cancelled at first.

[image]

If you attempt to check in again you will be able to check in without any further warnings. And without explicitly calling "Get latest version".

In the case the changes on both sides are the same change, this attempt to check-in will actually silently fail and will undo the local change in favor of the "newer" server version.

You can also force a checkin from the commandline (discardign server changes) using `tf vc checkin /force`.

Another case that can occur is that the file in question was unchanged, but part of a merge operation. In which case the "Merge" will be recorded as a new changeset, but the contents can remain the same.

I'm not aware of any other set of steps that can cause changes to be checked in without explicitly.

Comment: We do have that turned on however we never received any message. We are trying to replicate our issue again and can't seem to replicate it (we have replicated it in the past without issue but now we are getting the conflict!)

Comment: Any chance you've ever used 'keep target'  or 'keep source'  while merging?  That will also 'stick' and totally ignore merges later on.